# Reaching a turning point in photon trajectory

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, geodesics, gravitational-lensing

Given the geodesic equations for a photon in a Schwarzchild or Kerr metric (provided by a near BH for example), the radial equation has usually  two possible signs:

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dr}{d\tau}= \pm \sqrt{R(r;b)}
\end{equation}

where $\tau$ is an affine parameter and $R(r)$ is also called radial potential and depends on the impact parameter $b$ (and also on the spin $a$ if the metric is Kerr). In literature, there are no information on how to select the correct sign. However, given an emission point, the choice of the sign is crucial:

a) if $\dfrac{dr}{d\tau}>0$, this means that the radial distance of the photon from the BH is *increasing*, and hence no turning point is reached $\rightarrow$ **direct** trajectory

b) if $\dfrac{dr}{d\tau}<0$, this means that the radial distance of the photon from the BH is *decreasing*, and hence no turning point is reached $\rightarrow$ **indirect** trajectory

The exact behavior, in my opinion, should depend on the azimuthal angle, i.e. on the position of the emission point along the orbit. Indeed, think of Superior ($\phi=\pi$) and Inferior ($\phi=0$) conjunction  points: they have the same impact parameter ($b=0$), but in the first case the trajectory is indirect, while in the second case it is direct.

So the question is: how to determine the correct sign of $\dfrac{dr}{d\tau}$ as a function of the position along the orbit, in order to correctly distinguish, for each emission position, if the the trajectory is direct or indirect ?

Comment: For trajectories with turning points you need to use the d²r/dτ² from the geodesic equation, otherwise you have to change the sign manually every time the dr/dτ becomes 0.

Comment: @Yukterez $d^2 r / d \tau^2$ computed at the emission point or at the turning point ?

Comment: @Yukterez Or you just solve the equations analytically and pick the smooth branch of the solution.

Comment: @gravitone123 - the 2. derivatives are evaluated all the way along the whole differential equation. The 0. and 1. derivatives are the initial conditions and the output. For those components that have no ± in the 1. derivative you can drop the 2. derivative and express the 1. derivative in terms of the constants of motion like energy, axial angular momentum and carter constant, see [Fuerst & Wu, p. 4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0406401.pdf#page=4) and the solution for Schwarzschild [here @ output 8-11](http://relativity.yukterez.net/06.html#8)

Answer (score 1):

At any “emission point” there will be photon trajectories for both signs. They are both equally correct. Either, both, or neither may reach a particular observer.

Comment: Sure. Indeed, my question was how to determine the correct sign for a given geometry (emission_point-BH-observer). Suppose the observer is at $\phi=0$; for each value of the impact parameter $b$ there are two different emission points: one with a direct path towards  me (no turning point), and one with an indirect path (with turning point). Without lensing, the "window" for direct photons would be $\phi \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ from intuitive considerations, but in presence of lensing the window changes. So, How I generally determine the extreme angles of this window ?